# Can I make an exception for a route in Express?

Tags: node.js, express, url, axios

Following is the code I am referring to,

```
axios.get('http://localhost:1337/')
.then( response => {
var dataSet = response.data;

// URL Handle for Data page
app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
     res.render('data', {
         data = dataSet
     });
});

})
.catch( error => {
   console.log('An error occurred: ' + error);
});

// URL Handle for Contact page
app.get('/contact', (req, res) => {
   res.render('contact');
});

// URL Handle for Error page
app.all('*', (req, res) => {
   res.render('error');
});
```

Now, as I am using Axios for fetching the response from the database, I am also rendering the data in that desired page where I want the response of the API.

But there's a problem when I am using "app.all" handler for the wrong URL handle, it redirects to the error page.

**I need a solution in which there can be an exception which can be added to the "app.all" handler and whenever the handle is '/data' it does not redirect to '/error'.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your route for `/data` is registered after the async call of `axios` is completed.

Try, putting `axios` call inside route handler

```
app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
  axios.get('http://localhost:1337/').then( response => {
    var dataSet = response.data;
    res.render('data', {
      data: dataSet
    });
  })
  .catch( error => {
    console.log('An error occurred: ' + error);
  });
});


// URL Handle for Contact page
app.get('/contact', (req, res) => {
  res.render('contact');
});

// URL Handle for Error page
app.all('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('error');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use axios in controller, so code should look like this:

```
app.get('/data', async (req, res, next) => {
     try{
       const { body }  = await axios.get('http://localhost:1337/')

       res.render('data', {
         data : body
       });
     }catch(error){
       next(error)
     }
});
```

As You see, if there is error You should call `next` function with error instance and then create middleware as `errorHandler` to catch it.